# I added olive oil to my cake, but I haven’t baked it yet

Tags: baking, cake, butter, olive

The taste is so strong, and I haven’t even baked it yet.
How do I make it taste better?
I added it as a butter substitute... now what do i do?

Comment: Did you use extra virgin olive oil? EVOO has a much stronger grassy taste than "ordinary", cheaper olive oil.

Comment: Better than what? What are the other flavors in the batter? Maybe they can compensate the strenght of the olive oil maybe not. As Stephie says, bake and taste ;)

Comment: What color was your oil?
The darker in color, the stronger the flavor. The lighter shade has a more delicate taste.

Answer (score 6):

First, you could bake it as planned. The taste may become less pronounced, especially in comparison to the other, still developing flavors from caramelizing and the Maillard reaction during baking.

There are quite a few cake recipes that use olive oil (so it’s not necessarily a bad idea), and often they use citrusy and slightly savory flavor combinations, e.g. a pound cake with rosemary and orange or a lemon cake. (Not sure whether olive oil would work too well with, say, milk chocolate.) You could take that approach as an inspiration: If there's still time, add e.g. some lemon peel. If not, you can combine the baked cake with a citrus marmalade or a glaze.

Comment: I think it would go quite well in a lemon and rosemary cake, or possibly even lemon and lavender (delicious in a cake and rather rare). Or you could probably mask it by turning it into a ginger cake.

Comment: @ChrisH Done both of the former ;-)

Comment: I've got them growing in the garden but my baking these days is to suit  a child's taste and I don't think they'd tempt her. A special batch may be in order, probably a small one if it's all for me

Answer (score 0):

**Lo - it is become crust.  And there was cake pizza!**

Bake it thin.  Then get it out and put sauce on and cheese.  Pepperoni if your child is digging it.

*It is cake pizza*.  You will be hailed down the generations of your family as the semidivine inventor of cake pizza.  I feel like it might be a cousin of bacon pancakes.

Can we make cake pizza today?

dang now I really want cake pizza.